# Why the print('\n', 'abc') in Python 3 is giving new line and an empty space?

Tags: python-3.x

I was just expecting a new line character and written below code.

```
>>> print('\n', 'abc')

 abc
>>>
```

But it gave single space also in front of the string abc, may I know why it added that space?

I am using Python 3.9 in Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

If given more than one argument, `print` joins them with spaces, so you are effectively doing `print("\n abc")`.

Answer (score 0):

The default separator (sep) argument to the print function is a whitespace. Change it for a empty string to remove that single space indentation:

```py
print('\n', 'abc', sep='')
```